# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::trans does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have upgraded my laravel application from 5.3 to 8.83. When logging in with the correct credentials everything is fine. But with the wrong username or password, the error is thrown.
I don't know where the method trans() is called and hence causing the problem.
I have gone through almost all of the suggested solutions online but unsuccessful.

Here is my Translator class

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Translation;

use Countable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Loader;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator as TranslatorContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class Translator extends NamespacedItemResolver implements TranslatorContract
{
    use Macroable;

    /**
     * The loader implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Loader
     */
    protected $loader;

    /**
     * The default locale being used by the translator.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $locale;

    /**
     * The fallback locale used by the translator.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fallback;

    /**
     * The array of loaded translation groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loaded = [];

    /**
     * The message selector.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Translation\MessageSelector
     */
    protected $selector;

    /**
     * Create a new translator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Loader  $loader
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Loader $loader, $locale)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;

        $this->setLocale($locale);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if a translation exists for a given locale.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasForLocale($key, $locale = null)
    {
        return $this->has($key, $locale, false);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if a translation exists.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @param  bool  $fallback
     * @return bool
     */
    public function has($key, $locale = null, $fallback = true)
    {
        return $this->get($key, [], $locale, $fallback) !== $key;
    }

    /**
     * Get the translation for the given key.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @param  bool  $fallback
     * @return string|array
     */
    public function get($key, array $replace = [], $locale = null, $fallback = true)
    {
        $locale = $locale ?: $this->locale;

        // For JSON translations, there is only one file per locale, so we will simply load
        // that file and then we will be ready to check the array for the key. These are
        // only one level deep so we do not need to do any fancy searching through it.
        $this->load('*', '*', $locale);

        $line = $this->loaded['*']['*'][$locale][$key] ?? null;

        // If we can't find a translation for the JSON key, we will attempt to translate it
        // using the typical translation file. This way developers can always just use a
        // helper such as __ instead of having to pick between trans or __ with views.
        if (! isset($line)) {
            [$namespace, $group, $item] = $this->parseKey($key);

            // Here we will get the locale that should be used for the language line. If one
            // was not passed, we will use the default locales which was given to us when
            // the translator was instantiated. Then, we can load the lines and return.
            $locales = $fallback ? $this->localeArray($locale) : [$locale];

            foreach ($locales as $locale) {
                if (! is_null($line = $this->getLine(
                    $namespace, $group, $locale, $item, $replace
                ))) {
                    return $line;
                }
            }
        }

        // If the line doesn't exist, we will return back the key which was requested as
        // that will be quick to spot in the UI if language keys are wrong or missing
        // from the application's language files. Otherwise we can return the line.
        return $this->makeReplacements($line ?: $key, $replace);
    }

    /**
     * Get a translation according to an integer value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  \Countable|int|array  $number
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @return string
     */
    public function choice($key, $number, array $replace = [], $locale = null)
    {
        $line = $this->get(
            $key, $replace, $locale = $this->localeForChoice($locale)
        );

        // If the given "number" is actually an array or countable we will simply count the
        // number of elements in an instance. This allows developers to pass an array of
        // items without having to count it on their end first which gives bad syntax.
        if (is_array($number) || $number instanceof Countable) {
            $number = count($number);
        }

        $replace['count'] = $number;

        return $this->makeReplacements(
            $this->getSelector()->choose($line, $number, $locale), $replace
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the proper locale for a choice operation.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @return string
     */
    protected function localeForChoice($locale)
    {
        return $locale ?: $this->locale ?: $this->fallback;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a language line out the loaded array.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string  $group
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @param  string  $item
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @return string|array|null
     */
    protected function getLine($namespace, $group, $locale, $item, array $replace)
    {
        $this->load($namespace, $group, $locale);

        $line = Arr::get($this->loaded[$namespace][$group][$locale], $item);

        if (is_string($line)) {
            return $this->makeReplacements($line, $replace);
        } elseif (is_array($line) && count($line) > 0) {
            foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
                $line[$key] = $this->makeReplacements($value, $replace);
            }

            return $line;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make the place-holder replacements on a line.
     *
     * @param  string  $line
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @return string
     */
    protected function makeReplacements($line, array $replace)
    {
        if (empty($replace)) {
            return $line;
        }

        $shouldReplace = [];

        foreach ($replace as $key => $value) {
            $shouldReplace[':'.Str::ucfirst($key ?? '')] = Str::ucfirst($value ?? '');
            $shouldReplace[':'.Str::upper($key ?? '')] = Str::upper($value ?? '');
            $shouldReplace[':'.$key] = $value;
        }

        return strtr($line, $shouldReplace);
    }

    /**
     * Add translation lines to the given locale.
     *
     * @param  array  $lines
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @return void
     */
    public function addLines(array $lines, $locale, $namespace = '*')
    {
        foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
            [$group, $item] = explode('.', $key, 2);

            Arr::set($this->loaded, "$namespace.$group.$locale.$item", $value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load the specified language group.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string  $group
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return void
     */
    public function load($namespace, $group, $locale)
    {
        if ($this->isLoaded($namespace, $group, $locale)) {
            return;
        }

        // The loader is responsible for returning the array of language lines for the
        // given namespace, group, and locale. We'll set the lines in this array of
        // lines that have already been loaded so that we can easily access them.
        $lines = $this->loader->load($locale, $group, $namespace);

        $this->loaded[$namespace][$group][$locale] = $lines;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given group has been loaded.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string  $group
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isLoaded($namespace, $group, $locale)
    {
        return isset($this->loaded[$namespace][$group][$locale]);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new namespace to the loader.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string  $hint
     * @return void
     */
    public function addNamespace($namespace, $hint)
    {
        $this->loader->addNamespace($namespace, $hint);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new JSON path to the loader.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return void
     */
    public function addJsonPath($path)
    {
        $this->loader->addJsonPath($path);
    }

    /**
     * Parse a key into namespace, group, and item.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return array
     */
    public function parseKey($key)
    {
        $segments = parent::parseKey($key);

        if (is_null($segments[0])) {
            $segments[0] = '*';
        }

        return $segments;
    }

    /**
     * Get the array of locales to be checked.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @return array
     */
    protected function localeArray($locale)
    {
        return array_filter([$locale ?: $this->locale, $this->fallback]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the message selector instance.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Translation\MessageSelector
     */
    public function getSelector()
    {
        if (! isset($this->selector)) {
            $this->selector = new MessageSelector;
        }

        return $this->selector;
    }

    /**
     * Set the message selector instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Translation\MessageSelector  $selector
     * @return void
     */
    public function setSelector(MessageSelector $selector)
    {
        $this->selector = $selector;
    }

    /**
     * Get the language line loader implementation.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Loader
     */
    public function getLoader()
    {
        return $this->loader;
    }

    /**
     * Get the default locale being used.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function locale()
    {
        return $this->getLocale();
    }

    /**
     * Get the default locale being used.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    /**
     * Set the default locale.
     *
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        if (Str::contains($locale, ['/', '\\'])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid characters present in locale.');
        }

        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

    /**
     * Get the fallback locale being used.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFallback()
    {
        return $this->fallback;
    }

    /**
     * Set the fallback locale being used.
     *
     * @param  string  $fallback
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFallback($fallback)
    {
        $this->fallback = $fallback;
    }

    /**
     * Set the loaded translation groups.
     *
     * @param  array  $loaded
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLoaded(array $loaded)
    {
        $this->loaded = $loaded;
    }
}
```

Here is my app/config.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    */

    'name' => 'HRMIS',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://hrmis.aicc.co.tz'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

    'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\ServiceProvider::class,


        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
        Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider::class,
        Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,



        //

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
        'Calendar' => MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar::class,
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
        'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,


    ],

];
```

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.12",
        "doctrine/common": "^3.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "illuminate/support": "*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.3",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.0",
        "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.19",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "*",
        "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
            
        },
        "files" : ["app/helpers.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: It's best to look at the stack trace of the logs to find the file that is throwing this exception. Could it be a translation in your controller at the time you validate the credentials?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lucas, your insight helped me a lot to figure out the problem and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
The **trans()** instance causing error was in
**\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php**

I replaced the **trans** with **__** and the problem was solved.

Again I got the error
**Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist**

After reading the Laravel documentation guide on upgrading Laravel I found out that
**Laravel 6+ has replaced Translator getFromJson() to get()**. I found and replaced all instances of **getFromJson** with **get()**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, nothing to worry in this regards.
It happens due to the update of the Laravel version from 5.xx to 8.xx

It is most common that some **packages/dependencies/vendors/libraries** may not be included in the higher versions or such **packages/dependencies/vendors/libraries** may partially/fully be removed in the next/upcoming higher updates.

In your case, the responsible **packages/dependencies/vendors/libraries** which causes to happen this error (**Illuminate\Translation\Translator::trans does not exist**) is not updated to the higher version of the Laravel.

So what you can do in this case is, **to just change your source accordingly and/or rewrite the source code that is compactible to the higher Laravel version (ie, 8.xx, in your case)**, and if needed, please perform exception handling also.